# Jquery: Smooth transiton effect while changing classes in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML page where I have 3 divs. Initally 2 are visible(col1, col2) and one is hidden(col3). On button click, I want to hide the second div, change size of first and make third one visible. I want to do this with a smooth transition effect. The divs are as follows:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="col1" class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="lead">Chart title goes here</div>
                </div>
                <div id="col2" class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="lead">Second Div</div>
                    <button id="trig" class="btn btn-contrast">Reflow 
                     Me</button>
                </div>
                <div id="col3" class="col-sm-8 hidden">
                    <div class="lead">Fill form</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

The script that I currently have only changes the classes but the transition is very abrupt.

```
<script>
    $("#trig").click(function(){
        $("#col1").toggleClass("col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3");
        $("#col2").toggleClass("hidden");
        $("#col3").removeClass("hidden");
    });
</script>
```

I tried this link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/5/ but this didn't work out well for me. I am new to CSS and jQuery and don't exactly understand what to do. Kindly help!

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the fiddle you mention? Don't you understand the CSS, or can't you make it work on your own project? If it's the latter, you should provide the CSS from your project so it's easier to help you out! :)

Comment: I am not able to unerstand how to apply this fiddle on my HTML page. I tried applying different classes given in the fiddle but the alignment of all elements gets disturbed. I just want a simple transition between the divs. I don't have any other CSS included in the page.

Comment: I see your problem. I've added an answer that might help you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You had your ease set to 0.3s, so it took 0.3 seconds to complete.  I changed it to 1.0s [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5huyv1y6/).

The code is as follows:

```
.row-fluid div {
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1.0s ease, margin 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1.0s ease, margin 1.0s ease;
    -o-transition: width 1.0s ease, margin 1.0s ease;
    transition: width 1.0s ease, margin 1.0s ease;
}
```

Note that this is using transitions, not JQuery.

If you have something in JQuery you'd like to be looked at specifically, you'll need to link us to something with it implemented, the code you have given doesn't include the classes needed by the code.

Answer (score 0):

So given your HTML and script, I would recommend changing your script a bit:

```
$("#trig").click(function(){
    $("#col1").toggleClass("col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3");
    $("#col2").hide();
    $("#col3").show(2000);
});
```

Basically what this does is that when you click the button you do:

1. Toggle (switch) from `col-sm-8` to `col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3` on your div with ID `col1`.
2. Hide the div with ID `col2`, what this does is basically append the class `hidden` to that div. I recommend NOT using animation on this one to avoid too many conflicting animations!
3. Removes the class `hidden` from the div with ID `col3`. Notice the parameter `2000` in the show function? That means it should use 2 seconds to display this div.

In addition I've added some pretty basic CSS to allow animations when switching class on divs. In this case it's the div with ID `col1`.

```
#col1 {
  background: red;
}

#col2 {
  background: green;
}

#col3 {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}

[class*='col-sm'] {
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38884/

---

Oh and by the way:

Notice what I mean about competing animations? It's lagging when multiple animations are running at the same time.

You could implement event listeners to start animate in the new div when the first is removed, or maybe use jQuery `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` since they have the possibility to add a function once it's finished.

For instance:

```
$('#col2').fadeOut(2000, function() {
  $('#col3').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

What this does is that it fades out the div with ID `col2`, and once that's not visible anymore it starts fading in the div with ID `col3`. Maybe this would be a better solution?